# SSDT Doesn't import table indexes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I am importing a database using SSDT, but the indexes are not loaded into my sqlproj.

I tried to update the script in my project and publish it, but it is ignored on publishing. All the options for indexes are selected on schema compare options.

Comment: [Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Have to agree with Eric. What's going on? What happens if you try to publish to a new database? Do the indexes already exist in the target because they should be ignored in that case. If you create a new project and point it at a DB that has the tables/indexes, does _that_ import everything?